# How do you disable personalization for an sap.m.column in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I have a column in my table for a inserting a custom checkbox in place of the standard which appears on making table in mode MultiSelect.

i do not want this column to appear in the personalization dialog box of the table. How do i disable or hide this entry in the list.

Comment: are you using the p13nDialog? Or do you create the dialog like that: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.56.10/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TablePerso/code?

Comment: Yes I am using it as shown in the link you shared.

Comment: @AnanthalakshmiSankar did you get any solution for this? Am having same issue. I want to disable the selection or hide one column from the personalization box.